# Installing the Liquorix kernel on ubuntu 12.04 x64bit

Tags: kernel

Has anyone had any luck installing the Liquorix kernel for 3.6.6 or any of the newer ones??
I want to install it on Ubuntu 12.04x64.
Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got it its well..... still installing:

do this first:

```
echo "deb http://liquorix.net/debian sid main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/liquorix.list
echo "deb-src http://liquorix.net/debian sid main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/liquorix.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install '^liquorix-([^-]+-)?keyring.?'
```

run this to check the repos

```
apt-cache search liquorix
```

it will show the available kernels.............

install linux-headers and linux-image using:

```
sudo apt-get install  linux-header-3.6.0.....  linux-image-3.6.0.......
```

if you get gcc4.7 dependency error, install it FIRST!! and then install the kernel as per the above command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```

done 
just reboot

yes its alive!!!

A personal Opinion: This is something id like to see happen with linux before my hair turns gray:
Boottoram to a  extent allows you to run ubuntu completely from ram.
Today 16gb/32 gb can be had for pennies...
I want to see a kernel that first allows installing on disk and allowing to run/load from ram once the Os is installed at the users behest and handling errors and saving changes...obviously and without guarantee.
This means drivers and other critical stuff loading from main memory and if errors are generated the kernel can reference from disk(ssd/hdd).
If a mechanism as such exists please suggest.
Using default linux kernels renders linux and ubuntu in a zombie state...we need something more customized and gpu friendly