# IdeaPad Y510p and GNU/Linux

Tags: hardware, lenovo, compatibility

Do you know if IdeaPad Y510p is compatible with GNU/Linux?

Click [here](http://canada.lenovo.com/sdshop/SEUILibrary/controller/e/webca/LenovoPortal/en_CA/catalog.workflow%3aitem.detail?GroupID=458&Code=59369997&category_id=3B20BA877A2C60BD831C560F83B08DDE) for the IdeaPas Y510p!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's very subjective to say whether it is compatible or not. Even I cannot say that for myself, since I've had quite a lot of trouble until I got my system in a state that I wanted to. But I guess it is always the case when you are trying to install GNU/Linux on a laptop and especially on a newer one.

I have the very same model (Lenovo Y510p) with Ubuntu 13.10 installed which is currently running quite well. My model is the one with only one graphics card (Nvidia GeForce GT755M).

---

Let me try and break down the current state of my machine:

#### Graphics:

I'm currently using the integrated Intel GPU for the system and I'm able to use Nvidia for a process with a command. ([Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)) Actually this is just what I want since I don't want my laptop heating up without any need just because it's using the Nvidia graphics. And it saves a bit of battery power to use the integrated Intel GPU as well :) So you only call the heavy artillery (Nvidia) when it's needed. There are still a few glitches that need to be fixed. (e.g, The brightness is automatically set to 0 when booting and I need to set it up manually with my keyboard.) But for now I'm happy.

#### Audio I/O:

No issues so far. Works like a charm.

#### Bluetooth:

Works fine but has a few problems as well. (e.g., When you resume from sleep, my devices are not able to connect.) So far I have found some workarounds but they are not very convenient.

#### Touchpad:

After some set up it works pretty decent.

---

I cannot currently think of other things that could be relevant to what you would demand from your machine. Please feel free to ask me if you want to know something more.

If I (personally and subjectively) had to give some compatibility score, it'd be:

**Compatibility with Ubuntu: 5/10**

I'm yet giving such a low score, since I would expect all the things to work out of the box without the need to further configure and tweak.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I bought one with no OS installed and it was relatively easy to install Ubuntu (1 Nvidia 755m). You need to disable UEFI and set "nomodeset in the installation screen ([My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)).

I tried 13.10 and 12.04.3. On 13.10 everything works except brightness controls. The brighntness is always at maximum no matter what you do. Since I was unable to solve this (and I tried basically everything) and moved to 12.04. The only issue was (again) brightness which was set to minimum at startup. However I solved it by typing this on the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and editing the following line as below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=\"!Windows 2012\""
```

I had problems with the wireless connection, it was slow and unstable. I found a solution for Linux Ubuntu but I'm not entirely sure why or how it works.

I installed the kernel 3.12-6.dmz.1-liquorix-amd64 using these instructions:

[Installing the Liquorix kernel on ubuntu 12.04 x64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218382/installing-the-liquorix-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64bit)

I had tried the "regular" kernel 3.12.6 but with no success:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/kernel-3-12-4-install-upgrade-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Brightness control works fine after I set driver correctly: [Lenovo y510p with HDMI monitor (RESOLVED)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407009/lenovo-y510p-with-hdmi-monitor-resolved)

I don't use nvidia, just Intel HD4600