# Slow wireless on Linux Ubuntu 12.04.3 (lenovo y510p)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless

I have a Lenovo Ideapad y510p (Intel Centrino 2230 and kernel `3.8.0-34-generic`), running Ubuntu 12.04.3 and I'm getting consistently lower wireless internet speeds when compared with my old computer's.

In the same room the old computer returns 30.34 Mbps while the Lenovo returns 8 Mbps.

I've tried to add `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-disable11n.conf` and to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` but there was no change.

What else can I do?

References:

[How to fix slow wireless on machines with Intel wireless cards?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119578/how-to-fix-slow-wireless-on-machines-with-intel-wireless-cards)

Comment: I found a solution for Linux Ubuntu but I'm not entirely sure why or how it works.

I installed the kernel 3.12-6.dmz.1-liquorix-amd64 using this instructions:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/218382/installing-the-liquorix-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-x64bit

I had tried the "regular" kernel 3.12.6 but with no success:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/kernel-3-12-4-install-upgrade-ubuntu-linux/